# How to write to already opened FD in golang

Tags: go, pipe, fifo

I have the following opened FD (lsof output):

```
auth    11780 root    5w  FIFO               0,10      0t0  72061824 pipe
```

I need to write something in FD 5 (FIFO) in go. In C it is performed by the syscall write():

```
19270 write(5, "*************", 12 <unfinished ...>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: FD 5 is opened by the parent process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`os.NewFile`](https://godoc.org/os#NewFile) to "open" an existing file by its file descriptor:

> ```
> func NewFile(fd uintptr, name string) *File
> ```
>
> NewFile returns a new File with the given file descriptor and name.

```
file := os.NewFile(5, "pipe")
_, err := file.Write([]byte(`my data`))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```